# find all rows that have two minutes difference in date

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-difference

I have a table `ACQUISITION`, with 1 720 208 rows.

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id           | date                    | value     |
|--------------|-------------------------|-----------|
| 1820188      | 2011-01-22 17:48:56     | 1.287     |
| 1820187      | 2011-01-21 21:55:11     | 2.312     |
| 1820186      | 2011-01-21 21:54:00     | 2.313     |
| 1820185      | 2011-01-20 17:46:10     | 1.755     |
| 1820184      | 2011-01-20 17:45:05     | 1.785     |
| 1820183      | 2011-01-19 18:21:02     | 2.001     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Following a problem I need to find every rows that have less than two minutes difference.

Ideally I should be able to find here:

```
| 1820187      | 2011-01-21 21:55:11     | 2.312     |
| 1820186      | 2011-01-21 21:54:00     | 2.313     |
| 1820185      | 2011-01-20 17:46:10     | 1.755     |
| 1820184      | 2011-01-20 17:45:05     | 1.785     |
```

I'm quite lost here, if you got any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us restate your question in a subtle fashion so we can make this query complete before the heat-death of the universe.

"I need to know the *consecutive* records in the table with timestamps closer together than two minutes."

We can tie the notion of "consecutive" to your id values.

Try this query and see if you get decent performance (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28738/2/0)

```
SELECT a.date first_date, a.id first_id, a.value first_value,
       b.id second_id, b.value second_value,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.date, b.date) delta_t
  FROM thetable AS a
  JOIN thetable AS b  ON b.id = a.id + 1 
                     AND b.date <= a.date + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

The self-join workload is brought to heel with `ON b.id = a.id + 1`. And, avoiding a function on one of the two `date` column values allows the query to exploit any index that's available on that column.

Creating a covering index on `(id,date,value)` will help performance of this query.

If the consecutive-row assumption doesn't work in this dataset, you can try this, to compare each row to the next ten rows. It will be slower.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28738/6/0)

```
SELECT a.date first_date, a.id first_id, a.value first_value,
       b.id second_id, b.value second_value,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.date, b.date) delta_t
  FROM thetable AS a
  JOIN thetable AS b  ON b.id <= a.id + 10
                     AND b.id >  a.id 
                     AND b.date <= a.date + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

If the `id` values are entirely worthless as a way of ordering your rows, you'll need this. And, it will be very slow. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28738/5/0)

```
SELECT a.date first_date, a.id first_id, a.value first_value,
       b.id second_id, b.value second_value,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.date, b.date) delta_t
  FROM thetable AS a
  JOIN thetable AS b  ON b.date <= a.date + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
                     AND b.date >  a.date
                     AND b.id <> a.id
```

Comment: This looks specifically at consecutive rows - which means making two assumptions about the data (but only one of which is, to my mind, reasonable)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for ! Thank you for your time and your explanations Ollie, I used the first query to delete 253 000  duplicate data in few minutes !

Answer (score 0):

Do a `SELF JOIN` with the table and use `TIMEDIFF()` function like

```
SELECT t1.* 
from ACQUISITION t1 JOIN ACQUISITION t2
ON TIMEDIFF(t1.`date`, t2.`date`) <= 2;
```

Comment: I am wainting... did this query make 1 720 208 ^ 1 720 208 requests ?

Comment: Yes, it is making that many comparisons. See you next week  :-)

Comment: Promiscuous self-join: returns all pairs of records with a negative time offset as well as those with a positive offset in the specified range.

Comment: Um, this joins every row to itself